# How to change appearance of URL from within a PHP script

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have some PHP and HTML in the same file, and I am not exactly sure how to make the URL appear as the name of that page.

Here is an example of what I would like to do: lets say some page id = 1 and the title of that page is HelloWorld.

Instead of `site.com/page.php?id=1` I would like the url to appear as `site.com/HelloWorld`

But the problem I am having is that I only get to know the title of the page inside that page after I query for the title by id.

Considering the setup I described, is there a way to make the urls appear as the names of the pages? And also, if someone links to that page by using the better looking url with the name of the page instead of the id, is there still a way to get the id and by that, the rest of the page contents?

Thanks!!

Comment: You'll want to check out the many frameworks and CMS's that make this happen to see how they accomplish it (Drupal, CakePHP, RoR, Symfony, etc...).

Comment: Well, so you need to query the pageName by id and want the pageName in the url? I guess this is simply impossible, as you won't get the correct page. So either add the pageId there too (like `site.com/1/Helloworld`) or change your script so you can get the page by using the name.

Comment: @Boo ah ok you might be on the right track here! How do I accomplish this with the url as you suggested? Get the id and name and then do a 301 from within the script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to learn more on how .htaccess work.

Here is a good link that got me started:

[.htaccess tricks and tips](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php)

Update:

Here is a very common practice in many framework where all requests are sent to index.php, and from there you use php to serve the correct page:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.site.com/index.php [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: thanks ...I am not exactly sure how this would work still. So I'd get the id and then redirect? I have two conditions: 1) Where I get an incoming id and by that I query for name, and try to then make a pretty url.  And the opposite condition where the url is pretty and I have to dynamically figure out which id it belongs to.

Comment: with this format you can have somethink like this : `http://site.com/1/HelloWorld` where you 1 is the id, and you parse the url to extract the id.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a function of your HTTP server software (often Apache), not of PHP.

What you're seeing happen on sites with "friendly" URLs is that the friendly name is captured in a Regular Expression and then passed to PHP.

For example:

```
GET /HelloWorld
```

is sent to your web server.. the web server parses it

```
RewriteCond ^(A REGULAR EXPRESSION TO CAPTURE YOUR FRIENDLY NAME)$
RewriteRule page.php?id=(EXPRESSION FROM ABOVE)
```

In this way your PHP script will always receive the friendly name as a parameter.

Take a look at "mod_write" for Apache - which you can often create rules for using an ".htaccess" file in the root directory.

Comment: thanks, the difficulty I am having is not knowing what the names will be.  They are not hard-coded and made up by users mostly.  Would the regular expression way of doing things still work in my case?

Comment: The regular expression just captures part of the URL.  For example you could do /userpages/(.*)/ and it would capture /userpages/frank/ or /userpages/justin/ and send it to you as $_POST['id'] = 'frank' or $_POST['id'] = 'justin'.  You can choose what to do with it then (e.g. send back a 404 if there isn't a page for that).