# ALL requests via index.php, no exceptions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I've seen a lot of good answers to this question, such as [Pretty URLs in PHP frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440490/pretty-urls-in-php-frameworks), however they all explicitly exclude existing files and directories, existing .php files, the index.php file itself and/or .css/.js/etc. I want *everything* directed to the index.php file, including the index.php file, where I can choose what to do with it dynamically, such as compression and minifying of css/js files or 404-ing most files that really exist.

I've been trying many things to get this done with varying and weird effects and looking at other answers for help, but there's always problems with whatever method I try. The closest working method I've found is also the simplest...

```
RewriteRule .* index.php?__path__=$0 [L]
```

However, the problem is that when I go to an existing folder without entering the trailing / e.g. `localhost/test` it redirects to `localhost/test/` - which it doesn't do if the directory doesn't exist on the server. This creates the very distinction between things that actually exist on the server and URL rewrites which I am trying to get rid of.

What's weirder, if I go to `127.0.0.1/test` (which may be a fix if some DNS cache quirk is causing this), it redirects to `http://127.0.0.1/test/?__path__=test`, which is totally bizarre (especially since going to `127.0.0.1/test/` avoids redirection completely, as intended, and no `[R]` was specified in the rewrite), and reveals the very kind of query stringy URL which I am trying to destroy. `/var=value` makes a much better format for query strings, but I digress. Of course, redirection doesn't happen with `127.0.0.1/testa` because the file doesn't exist, so Apache just seems to be doing something intentional I really don't want it to.

---

Also, since it is odd I couldn't find any other examples of this being done, are there any big downsides this? I hypothesise that aside from a slight amount of additional server load from starting up PHP and executing whatever it has to, there shouldn't be any problems - oh, and of course errors could destroy access to everything hosted. I am using the following code...

```
// trying to access a file directly?
if ($is_file) {
    // TODO: manage served files (gzip, minify, etc.)
    // is it an allowed extension?
    if (!is_array($CONFIG['allow_ext_access']) || !in_array($type, $CONFIG['allow_ext_access']))
        die('access denied');
    // it's not *this* file is it?
    if (!$is_index) {
        // try to get known file type
        $file_type = isset($CONFIG['file_types'][$type]) ? $CONFIG['file_types'][$type] : false;
        // if we have a file type we can properly pass it as what it is
        if ($file_type) {
            header('Content-Type: '.$file_type['mime']);
        }
        // execute php file or just output any other file
        if ($type == 'php') @include($path);
        else @readfile($path);
        die;
    }
}
// if it's not this file, then it's a path and a URL for re-routing
```

Comment: What's wrong with apache automatic trailing slash for existing folders ? What would you want instead ? Also, the fact that you get `http://127.0.0.1/test/?__path__=test` for instance is a normal behaviour since your rule matches everything at anytime. You need to add an exception for `index.php` to avoid a loop

Comment: @JustinIurman, If I add an exception for `index.php`, then my `index.php` has no idea that it needs to try to find a file called `index.php` - which I don't want it to do if the root directory is accessed because `index.php` isn't "there". And adding trailing slashes for existing folders means that if there happens to be a folder called "contact", one can't create a page called "contact" accessed via `/contact`. I don't want redirects at all, everything should just go to `index.php` and it will handle the request any explicitly defined ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am understanding it right you can use:

```
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule .* index.php?__path__=$0 [L,QSA]
```

`DirectorySlash Off` is used to disable adding a trailing slash after real directories as we are routing everything (including existing files / directories) to `index.php`.

Make sure to test it after clearing your browser cache.

We are using `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` variable here which is an internal `mod_rewrite` variable that is set to `200` after a successful internal rewrite. By checking

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
```

we're making sure that only first rewrite takes place and there is no looping.

Comment: Perfect, cache indeed made the old paths still redirect but I had plenty of uncache'd test directories to spare, thanks. I finally have the only .htaccess I'll ever need. An explanation on `ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS` might be nice too.

Comment: Glad it worked. I have added an explanation in my answer.