# Getting current metal price api in php

Tags: php

Hi i want to get current metal price value such as gold  using an valid api . I tried google it never find one . i can see live gold price here http://goldseek.com/ , https://goldprice.org/ . but i din't find api . So if some one can fetch current gold or silver price using php it will be very helpful

Comment: There's a lot of ways do this, you could use routing, you could rewrite every URL using htaccess... what have you tried so far? where are you stuck?

Comment: if you have any more details please share

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8441266/1207346

Comment: Please try this: https://gist.github.com/surferxo3/8b4eafe499f7fa52eacb6cc187d0a49a

Comment: but it showing Jun 18, 2017 , not the current date.. http://goldprice.org/NewCharts/gold/images/goldsilverpricesforcalculators.txt

Comment: Asking for off-site resources (such as API's, tutorials, sites, scripts etc) are off-topic here on SO. Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: @Dale - What does that post have to do with this question? Did you post it in the wrong tab?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Not sure what I was doing almost a year ago but thanks for pointing it out lol :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the second link https://goldprice.org/,

I got this,

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD');
$decoded = json_decode($json);
$item = $decoded->items;
$date = $decoded->date;
$gold_price = $item[0]->xauPrice;
echo "Gold price per Ounce on ".$date." is ".$gold_price;
```

Comment: Hi from where you got this https://data-asg.goldprice.org/dbXRates/USD ?

Comment: can i get the value in gm , kg etc ?\