# How to hide GET variable in address bar

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to change appearance of URL from within a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392965/how-to-change-appearance-of-url-from-within-a-php-script)

I have this in my address bar

> localhost/somedirectory/main.php?id=123456

how to hide those GET variables, so it becomes

> localhost/somedirectory/main/123456

I know .htaccess is the answer but my attempts so far are to no avail. Could someone please shed some light on how to achieve it?

Comment: can you post some of the code you've tried?  There are tons of .htaccess snippets out there.  Are you having trouble figuring out where to put the file?

Comment: @Zach L One of htaccess script I get from net nad it seems no to avail RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (/somedirectory/([a-z]+)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No way to do it with PHP the way you want!

Only htaccess will help for this task.

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase    /
RewriteRule ^localhost/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$    localhost/$1/$2.php?id=$3
```

Comment: thats what I mean ...how to do it with htaccess...mind to share...i've been follow several tutorial on net but it seems no to avail