# Display next line each time PHP script loads

Tags: php, php-5.3, file-handling

It's somehow a challenging task, because I am wondering if there is any way to access my next line of a text file each time I refresh my php script, without storing last count to database or locally within a file?

I know it sounds stupid, but I am just curious if there is any way that is still not in my knowledge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Session/cookie for store current line of file. Also you can take current line from your request.

For example, your url will be: file.php?line=1 and every refresh you have to redirect your page to file.php?line=2

```
<?php
$counter = "counter4";
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$counter])) {
    setcookie($counter, 1, time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
    echo "Current Line number: 1";
} else {
    $val = (int)$_COOKIE[$counter];
    //Increase line number;
    $val++;
    echo "Next Line number: " . $val;
    //make your file process


    //at the and set new line number
    setcookie($counter, $val, time() + (86400 * 365), "/");
}
?>
```

Comment: isn't it strange , i have to load with different url , but i don't want to change my url each time then what?

Comment: You beat me to it. It is also good to add client side localStorage to the answer as the asker did not rule the client side storage out.

Comment: @Mr.Z so you shoud focus on session or cookie. If you select session option when you close your browser your counter will be lost but if you choose cookie only your counter will be lost when you clean your cookies.

Comment: can you show me a demo , so i can better understand.

Answer (score 1):

So this goes down to where you want to store which line you left off of from the previous script. There are a few options:

1- Query String, which means saving it in the url. For example: www.foo.com/index.php?line=5

2- Query String and then change URL.
Same option as before, however if you don't want to have the ?line=5 at the end, you can use some php functions that change how the URL looks. Here is a link describing that process:
[How to change appearance of URL from within a PHP script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8392965/how-to-change-appearance-of-url-from-within-a-php-script)

3- Post method: this might be what you are looking for. When submitting a form, information can be sent to another php script using the "post" method which doesn't appear in the URL, and can be retrieved with something like:

```
<?php
$lineNumber = $_POST['line'];
?>
```

I assume that if you use this method, you would want to have the script do it automatically. One way you can do it is with javascript:

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('dateForm').submit(); // SUBMIT FORM
</script>
```

Comment: yes , method 3 is exactly useful in my case , merdincz demonstrated it thoroughly